# How to create custom LaunchScreen for appcelertor

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I can't run LaunchScreen for iOS in my project appcelerator.

Every time I change the storyboard for a personalized one the images do not appear when running the project

Help Please

Comment: Hey Felipe, to better help you with your problem, you need to add more detail describing the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to replace the static image on iOS, you shouldn't, because starting April 1st Apple will reject any app using those.

If you want to use a storyboard launchscreen, you can use the built-in one, or you can create a custom one. By default it uses the DefaultIcon.png and puts that on a solid background color, you can control this by adding this within the `<ios>` section

```
<default-background-color>#C7172C</default-background-color>
```

If you want to make a custom storyboard, you should follow the [guide in the documentation](https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/ios_launch_files.html), that is too long and complex to put in a simple answer on stackoverflow

Comment: thanks for your response. You save my project.

Sorry for my english. I'm not fluent